# How to rerender the component after props updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component like this, `<App>, <Main>, <GameFrame>`. In this  component, I have something like this

```
let faeko = new Faeko({}, client)
```

After the person enter the username, the `faeko` obj get initialized. Okay,then after initialized I'm passing this to child component as a props. But at that time its inner key-values are undefined. After some time it gets updated. Until that I cannot access the obj. What should I do until it gets updated.

Then only I need to access those values in other components and if its updated It should re-render the components

If something need free to ask, I'll update....

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to save the `faeko` object in a state, so once it is updated it will update the child component.

```
const [faeko, setFaeko] = useState(null);

const initializeFaeko = (client) => {
  setFaeko(new Faeko({}, client))
}

//... JSX
<GameFrame faeko={faeko}>
```

Second, In the child component, you need to check if the value of `faeko` is defined then show the content.

```
const GameFrame = ({ faeko }) => {
  return (
     // JSX CODE
     {faeko.username ? <h1>Welcome, {faeko.username}!</h1> : null}
  )
}
```